# Firebase: how to sort, filter and paginate a query on 'huge many-to-many" relation?

Tags: android, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a many-to-many relationship with more than thousands members between 2 Classes. For i.e. a "User" class and a "BigObject" containing many fields (name, modificationDate, category, status, etc.…) below the flattened data structure:

```
°User
    -uid1
        -username, etc...
        -bigObjectsRelation : "userBoIdxxxx"
    etc...

°BigObject
    -boId1
        -name : "aaa"
        -modificationDate : a timestamp
        - other fields etc ....
    -boId2
    etc...

°User_BigObject
    -userBoIdxxxx
         -boId2 : true
         -boId3 : true
         ....
         -boIdn : true
```

Since each user can have thousands of bigObject in relation how can build my client android query to get them for i.e. sorted by modification date and/or filtered by category, and how can I paginate through this list?

Comment: As a "nosql" database, Firebase doesn't have ability to directly do joins the way you can with SQL databases.  The following series (by Firebase guys) gives a good overview of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o

Comment: Parse-Server use also a nosql database and can manage this kind of query, so how can I do with firebase?